# Meteor how to handle multiple themes like wordpress?

Tags: meteor, content-management-system

I am thinking about changing a CMS I'm developing from the MEAN stack to meteor that will do a lot of the things that wordpress does. I am wanting the ability to have multiple themes that you can quickly switch between just like with wordpress. Does meteor have anything to accommodate this? What would be the best practices to set something like that up?

Currently I am foreseeing trouble with template name conflicts and routing based on individual themes.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular content management systems for Meteor is: https://github.com/orionjs/orion